# SQL Azure unique nonclustered constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Does SQL Azure support unique non-clustered constraints? Something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldA] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FieldB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FieldC] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [UQ_ABC] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([FieldA], [FieldB], [FieldC])
```

Comment: [What did the documentation tell you?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn305849.aspx) or what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

It is supported, between ending ) is missing in the above statement if that is troubling you